# Rollup Not Tree Shaking D3.js Correctly, Even With sideEffects Flag Set To False?

Tags: npm, d3.js, rollupjs, tree-shaking

When using rollup v3 to bundle my npm project that uses the D3.js v7 library to an es6 module for use on the browser, I am ending up with a lot of extra unnecessary code from D3.js in the produced bundle. This happens even with the sideEffects flag set to false in package.json, which seemed to be the solution to this issue when it was discussed a couple of years ago on this github issue: https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3076 . While treeshaking is definitely occuring, I'm still ending up with almost 1000 lines of code in my bundle from just importing one function (select from d3-selection).

Besides setting the sideEffects flag to false in package.json, is there anything else I need to do? I also tried setting moduleSideEffects to false in rollup.config, but this didn't seem to have any additional effect.

I have created a very simple example npm project that reproduces the issue. It is on github here: https://github.com/SpechtacularDave/rollupd3treeshake , or you can view the the example input index.js, package.json, and rollup.config.js below (but see the repo if you want to take a look at the output bundle since it's almost 1000 lines long).

```
// index.js
import {select} from "d3-selection";
select('#someid');
```

```
// rollup.config.js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
    input: 'index.js',
    output: {
        file: 'index.bundle.js',
        format: 'iife'
    },
    treeshake: {
        moduleSideEffects : false
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
    ],
}
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "rollupd3treeshake",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "d3-selection": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "rollup": "^3.10.0",
  "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1"
}
}
```

Can anyone provide any advice, or let me know if I'm misunderstanding something? Thanks.

Comment: `"sideEffects": false` is something that the implementer needs to add. If you look up `node_modules/d3-selection.package.json`, you will find it. I was able to see the effect of adding `treeshake: { moduleSideEffects : false }` to my rollup config, but it was insignificant (about 5% with the terser plugin)

Comment: Ah, thank you for clearing up that misunderstanding of mine. What's interesting is that if I delete the sideEffects flag entry from the d3 package, I get the same amount of output. This seems to indicate that it's not affecting anything (at least in my simple example). So my question remains, why is rollup including all this non necessary code?

Comment: Rollup complains about circular dependencies when I use d3. The author does not seem to be concerned about it. I wouldn't be surprised that even within d3-selection alone the dependencies are hard to track.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it turns out I had a misunderstanding of what treeshaking is able to accomplish. As curran on the github issue was able to explain to me, treeshaking only uses es6 import and export statements, so it doesn't know if my code invokes any other methods on the selection that I instantiated. So what I thought was unneccesary side effect code in my example is actually all necessary.